# Как можно вывести превью изображений сеткой, как в проводнике?

Tags: c#, изображения, grid, preview

Нужно вывести список изображений примерно также, как в винде они выводятся сеткой крупных или огромных превью. Это можно сделать только с помощью DataGridView Image или есть более простой способ/компонент?

Comment: Что используете забыли указать, WPF/WinForms? Если WPF - используйте `WrapPanel`, если `WinForms` - то наверно `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: WinForms. Пробую загрузить в GridView, но не получается пока заполнять динамически

Comment: А FlowLayoutPanel интересный вариант, спасибо. Попробую

Comment: Получилось, это то, что мне и нужно было! Спасибо!=) @EvgeniyZ если добавите это как ответ, могу отметить лучшим ответом.

Comment: Просто напишите в ответ то, что у вас получилось и этого достаточно)

Comment: Собственно сделал как в этом видео, только с PictureBox'ом в userControl'е - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL3aO1QkgvM